# What is the Ruby equivalent of the "this" function in Java?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Java there is a "this" function that points to its method. Is there an equivalent in Ruby? For instance, is there:

```
def method
  this.method
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Some real-life context?

Comment: You're probably looking for `self`, but I prefer if you actually understand what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent is `self`. It is also implict. So `self.first_name` is the same as `first_name` within the class unless you are making an assignment.

```
class Book
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  def full_name
     # this is the same as self.first_name + ", " + self.last_name
    first_name + ", " + last_name
  end
end
```

When making an assignment you need to use `self` explicitly since Ruby has no way of knowing if you are assigning a local variable called `first_name` or assigning to `instance.first_name`.

```
class Book    
  def foo
    self.first_name = "Bar"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's `self`, like:

```
def account_id
  self.account.id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

`self`

An example:

`self.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can call self.whatever on the class you are in, is that what you are looking for?