# setting the association ids before creating / saving the model record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have a before_create method in my model, which will check if the model has an association / relation with another model (user) and set it in case the relation is nil.

The problem is that I have no idea why the following condition won't be executed, although the user and user_id variables are nil.

The relation is:

```
User has_many :Leads
Campaign has_many :Leads
Lead belongs_to :User and :Campaign
```

Here's the model Lead code:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  belongs_to :popup
  belongs_to :campaign


  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }

  before_create :check_user_id

private
  def check_user_id
    puts "check user id: #{user_id}"
    puts self.user_id
    puts user_id
    puts user
    if self.user.blank?
      "set user id"
      user_id = campaign.user_id if campaign
    end

  end

end
```

The problem is that self.user.blank? condition will never be met. If I try user.nil? or unless user I always get the same thing, even though the user_id and user are nil. I also tried using self prefix like self.user.nil? , etc.

Why the condition is never met although the check_user_id method is executed?
What is the best way to set this relation when I create a new lead?

The lead is created under Campaign so the user Association should be set correctly:

```
c = Campaign.new
l = c.leads.new
l.email = 'test@test.com'
l.save
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self` for this to work.

```
 def check_user_id
    # snip...
    if self.user.blank?
      user_id = campaign.user_id if campaign
    end
  end
```

This is telling the method `check_user_id` to create a local variable called `user_id`. Instead you need to assign `instance.user_id`.

```
self.user_id = campaign.user_id if campaign
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709189/276959) for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. Its working now! Is there any better way to set this relation assignment automatically? Maybe with :through setting in the model relation?

Comment: The very short version of your code is: `self.user_id ||= campaign.try(:user_id)` (one line)