# Ruby: When to use self and when not to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I understand what Ruby self means, and I was trying to solve certain challenges on Tealeaf: http://www.gotealeaf.com/books/oo_workbook/read/intermediate_quiz_1

Here is the actual problem:

Snippet 1:

```
class BankAccount
  def initialize(starting_balance)
    @balance = starting_balance
  end

  # balance method can be replaced with attr_reader :balance
  def balance
    @balance
  end

  def positive_balance?
    balance >= 0 #calls the balance getter instance level method (defined above)
  end
end
```

Now for Snippet 1, running this code:

```
bank_account = BankAccount.new(3000)
puts bank_account.positive_balance?
```

prints true on the console, whereas for snippet 2:

Snippet 2:

```
class InvoiceEntry
  attr_reader :product_name

  def initialize(product_name, number_purchased)
    @quantity = number_purchased
    @product_name = product_name
  end

  # these are attr_accessor :quantity methods
  # quantity method can be replaced for attr_reader :quantity
  def quantity
    @quantity
  end

  # quantity=(q) method can be replaced for attr_writer :quantity
  def quantity=(q)
    @quantity = q
  end

  def update_quantity(updated_count)
    # quantity=(q) method doesn't get called
    quantity = updated_count if updated_count >= 0 
  end
end
```

Now for snippet 2, on running this code:

```
ie = InvoiceEntry.new('Water Bottle', 2)
ie.update_quantity(20)
puts ie.quantity #> returns 2
```

Why is this not updating the value?
Why is it working for the first case while not for the second?

Comment: In `update_quantity` you mistakenly assign to `quantity` (local variable) instead of `@quantity` (instance variable).

Comment: Take a look at this, particularly the section about implicitness:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709189/276959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning to `quantity` the local variable.

If you want to assign to the instance variable (via your `def quantity=` function) you need to do

`self.quantity = updated_count if updated_count >= 0`

Essentially, you're making a function call (`quantity=`) on `self`.

In snippet 1, `balance` is a pure function call because there is no assignment going on.

Comment: But accordingly, if you see in Snippet 1, balance should also act like a local variable, while balance>=0 refers to the method and gives the correct answer